# How to return generic methods?

Tags: java, generics, stack

I'm doing my homework right now and I stumbled on a, probably pretty easy, 'problem'.

I have to build a stack and I need to complete the following method:

```java
public E top()
    {   
        if(!isEmpty()) {
            /*
             * return top element
             * which would be st[pos-1]
             */
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I use

```java
//to save elements
private Object[] st;

//for position in array
private int pos = 0;
```

I tried to return my array, but it tells me "Cannot convert from Object to E". Now I don't know how to continue.

//edit: my constructor

```java
public Stack(int size)
    {
        st = new Object[size];
        //st = new E[size]; doesn't work

    }
```

Comment: Almost certainly not what your teacher was wanting you to do...  But you can create an array of `E`s of size `size` by adding `Class<E> klass` as a parameter to your constructor, and invoking `st = (E[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(klass, size);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast:

```
E element = (E) st[pos-1];
```

You will get an unchecked cast warning, though. This is safe to suppress, provided you ensure that only instances of `E` are added to the array.

```
void add(E element) {
  st[pos++] = element;
}
```

(And that is pretty much what `java.util.ArrayList` does, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Your Array should be of type E

```
private E[] st;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So there's no other way? Because I got the code like this from our teacher, it just needs completion. 
Now my constructor is struggling because it can't "create a generic array".

Comment: If you do it like this, you need either to provide an `E[]`, or a `Supplier<E[]>`, as a constructor parameter, because you can't create an array generically.